# Laravel + vue-router вложенные маршруты перекрывают api маршруты

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js, vue-router

Я пишу spa приложение на laravel vue. Чтобы управлять маршрутами через vue в laravel web.php я прописал следующее:

```js
<?php
Route::any( '/{any}', function(){
    return view('index');
})->where('any', '.*');
```

В файле api.php находятся маршруты от api, что понятно. То есть до них можно достучаться так `poorbirds.com/api/route`

Но, когда в приложении я перехожу по вложенным роутам, например `poorbirds.com/admin_area/birds`; то в местах, где я обращаюсь к апи, например: `/api/birds`; мне возвращается вместо json, который я ожидаю, html главной страницы.

Если сделать запрос к апи, например с такой страницы `poorbirds.com/birds`, то мне приходит то, что надо

Запросы к апи я посылаю через `axios`

```js
axios.get('api/auth/check_auth')
```

Я так понимаю проблема в web.php, но что...

Вот api.php

```js
<?php

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

Route::apiResource('birds', 'api\BirdsController');

Route::group([

    'middleware' => 'api',
    'prefix'     => 'auth',

], function ($router) {

    Route::post('register', 'AuthController@register');
    Route::post('login', 'AuthController@login')->name('login');
    Route::get('logout', 'AuthController@logout');
    Route::get('user', 'AuthController@user');
    Route::get('check_auth', 'AuthController@checkAuth');

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Посмотрев response, который возвращает сервер, я увидел, что `requestURL = http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin_area/api/auth/check_auth`
(Запрос отправлял с `http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin_area/birds`)
ТО есть получается, что он добавил лишнее "звено" - admin_area

Чтобы это исправить, нужно прописать baseURL для axios

```js
axios.defaults.baseURL = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000';
```

Answer (score 1):

Для того чтобы они не были перекрытыми, вам нужно сделать их разделение на уровне провайдера, так как это есть в примере базового проекта Laravel с использованием префикса.

```
<?php

class RouteServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
/**
 * This namespace is applied to your controller routes.
 *
 * In addition, it is set as the URL generator's root namespace.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $namespace = 'App\Http\Controllers';

/**
 * Define your route model bindings, pattern filters, etc.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function boot()
{
    //

    parent::boot();
}

/**
 * Define the routes for the application.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function map()
{
    $this->mapWebRoutes();

    $this->mapApiRoutes();

    //
}

/**
 * Define the "web" routes for the application.
 *
 * These routes all receive session state, CSRF protection, etc.
 *
 * @return void
 */
protected function mapWebRoutes()
{
    Route::group([
        'middleware' => 'web',
        'namespace' => $this->namespace,
    ], function ($router) {
        require base_path('routes/web.php');
    });
}

/**
 * Define the "api" routes for the application.
 *
 * These routes are typically stateless.
 *
 * @return void
 */
protected function mapApiRoutes()
{
    Route::group([
        'middleware' => 'api',
        'namespace' => $this->namespace,
        'prefix' => 'api',
    ], function ($router) {
        require base_path('routes/api.php');
    });
}
```

}

Comment: Абсолютно ничего не поменялось. Там уже было написано то же самое, только немного в другом виде ` Route::prefix('api')
            ->middleware('api')
            ->namespace($this->namespace)
            ->group(base_path('routes/api.php'));`

Comment: Добавьте ваши роуты в вопросе, @Colorkat

Comment: Добавил api.php, web.php уже был @Daniel

Comment: Ну, сможете вы подсказать?) @Daniel Protopopov

Comment: Единственный совет, который остался - это запустить отладку, и пройтись по коду, выяснив что же именно приводит к такому результату.

Comment: хмм, я посмотрел response, который возвращает сервер. И там request.responseURL = `http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin_area/api/auth/check_auth`. То есть получается лишнее звено admin_area. Запрос я отправлял с /admin_area_birds.

Comment: Юху, получилось. Проблема оказалась в axios! Он отправляет запрос на неправильный url. Чтобы это исправить нужно прописать base_url